# How do I backup Google Drive (Google Spreadsheets) file on regular basis using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, backup, google-docs

I have a critical business spreadsheet. I need to save copies regularly in case I need to see how the spreadsheet looked at a previous time.

I want this to happen automatically using Google Apps Script.

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate what you've tried already, and what went wrong? Where are you stuck?

Comment: do you know that there is a revision history available in every spreadsheet that saves all the changes that were made along with their dates and authors ? it is available under dthe file menu or by clicking on the 'Last edit' on top of the UI.

Comment: Any specific reason why you would not want to leverage the revision history for spreadsheets and instead want a separate copy of your spreadsheet ?

Comment: I have a lot of data and multiple spreadsheet users. Even a simple sort could really mess things up. Furthermore, the issue may go unnoticed until someone knowledgeable notices. I should look into the revision history capabilites, but for now, this helps me sleep at night.

Comment: Another reason, limited cells. I forget the exact limit (possibly 1 million), but,  this limit may be reached especially if recording lots of data into the sheet. Weekly backups plus purging older records would allow using spreadsheets if you want to record a lot of data but are only concerned with data on a weekly basis. Also, another spreadsheet may even access each weekly spreadsheet for analysis. I haven't done this myself, but, seems like a plausible solution depending on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the time driven triggers to run this code:

```
function backupSheet() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(FILE_ID);
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID); // backups folder
  var date = new Date();
  var ts = date.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");
  file.makeCopy(ts+':'+file.getName(), destination);
}
```